# Stripe Integration Error with Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I was following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Wbfk16jEOk&t=4052s) on django ecommerce and encountered a 404 error while trying to test out the Stripe application. Specifically, I was redirected to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/your-charge-code' upon submitting a test payment.

in views.py

```
def checkout(request):
    publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=1000,
                currency="gbp",
                description="Example charge",
                source=token,
                )
        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            pass

    context ={'publishKey': publishKey}
    template = 'checkout.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

in checkout.html:

```
{% block strip %}
<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('{{ publishKey }}');
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  if (response.error) { // Problem!
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission
  } else { // Token was created!
    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
}
</script>
{% endblock %}


{% block jquery %}
$(function() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');
    $form.submit(function(event) {
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled',true);
    Stripe.card.createToken($form,stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
    });
});
{% endblock %}
```

and in base.html

```
    {% block script %}    
    {% endblock %}

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    {% block jquery %}
    {% endblock %}

});
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does the "submit" button auto redirect me to a ./your-charge-code/ url? I'm new to django and web development and hope that some gurus here can guide me along. Thanks!

Comment: You have a form in your view that is used to submit the token created by Checkout and it likely has an action set to `/your-charge-code`, That's the part you need to change to mate the route for `views.py`.

Comment: hey koopajah, thanks. This solved my problem. I'm such a noob.